# Button and Textbox Not Inline

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the following code

```
        <div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header-myLeagues">Create A New League</li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="li-myLeagues">
                <asp:Label ID="LeagueNameLabel" runat="server">League Name:</asp:Label></li>
            <li class="li-myLeagues">
                <asp:TextBox ID="LeagueNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitNewLeagueButton" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" CommandName="SubmitNewLeague" Text="Submit" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

For some reason the button is not completely in line with the text box, any ideas how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the textbox and button in `<div></div>` and set css float:left to div's

```
<li class="li-myLeagues">
    <div style="float:left">
        <asp:TextBox ID="LeagueNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitNewLeagueButton" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" CommandName="SubmitNewLeague" Text="Submit" />
</div>        
</li>
```

add css to class `.li-myLeagues`

```
.li-myLeagues
{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to put your **CSS** as below

```
.li-myLeagues li
{
     display: inline;
      list-style-type: none;
     padding-right: 20px;
     float: left;
}
```

This is going to be usefull....

See [here is the same thing which I had made for you..](http://jsbin.com/imozon/1/)