# Button & Textbox not aligned properly

Tags: html, css

I would like my text box and search button to look like this:

```
--------------------    -------
|    Text Box      |    | BTN |
--------------------    -------
```

I am using this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200192/button-and-textbox-not-inline).

Here is how mine is rendered:

[image]

Here is my **CSHTML:**

```
<div style="display:inline-block; float: right">
    <div style="float:right;">
        @Html.TextBox("date", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; margin-right: 10px">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary top-margin" />
    </div>    
</div>
```

I know that inline CSS with HTML isn't preferred, and that I should separate out the CSS from the HTML, but for right now I just want to get this to render properly and then I will separate it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your code?

Comment: @BrunoToffolo https://jsfiddle.net/rpvb3q3o/ of course it works in jsfiddle but doens't in my code

Comment: If it works and JSFiddle but not in your code, there has to be an additional element whose CSS is affecting your layout more than you expect. The fiddle is not exactly as the image you posted above, there may be some CSS missing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you want. The `.example` is just a wrapper, you only need its contents.

```css
.example {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="example">

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="text box..." id="search-box" aria-describedby="search-label">
    <label for="search-box" id="search-label" class="input-group-addon btn">Search</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note: I made use of Twitter Bootstrap classes because it seems you are already loading it in your project. This can be easily done without Bootstrap, but it would mean unnecessary CSS if you load Bootstrap.

Comment: I would suggest using a label rather than a span since it wouldn't need to rely on aria spec support. If it is unavoidable to use the span I would use aria-labelledby instead of describedby since it is meant to be a label for the input. aria-describedby might be more useful for error message support, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Use table (with bootstrap 3):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="" id="input" class="form-control" value="" required="required" pattern="" title="">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The HTML Table Element (`<table>`) represents tabular data, as shown in [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), and should not be used to achieve this visual effect on layouting. It is preferred that he keeps using two `div`s, and align them accordingly through CSS.